# Highcharts: how to change the yAxis title programatically?

Tags: highcharts

I can change the title of a Highcharts chart with

```
chart.setTitle({text: 'The title'});
```

but I cannot change the vertical title yAxis.title, I tried

```
chart.yAxis.title = { text: 'The other title' };
chart.redraw();
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`axis.setTitle`-method](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setTitle), as in [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/69ZY3/2/).

The method takes in the parameters:

```
setTitle(Object title, [Boolean redraw])
```

Example code would be:

```
chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: 'The other title' });
```

The `yAxis` is an array since there may be multiple y-axis.